# Apache Spark Window Operation is not following by order

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark streaming application in python, which taking some event data from kafka and output the aggregation result to console by a window operation and watermark

but i found that the output is not i expected, the ordering is not correct

e.g
Event data

```
{"id": 292, "stock": "g", "price": 817, "time": "2023-03-06 17:32:52.596087"}
```

aggregation

```
//convert json data to schema
df_select = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)"). \
  select(from_json("value",schema).alias("data")). \
    select("data.*")

//taking the schema data to cut it by window with attribute named "time", and group by "stock"
df_agg = df_select.withWatermark("time", "10 seconds") \
.groupBy(
  window("time", "10 seconds"),
  "stock"
  ).agg(F.min("price").alias("min_price"), F.max("price").alias("max_price"))
```

how ever i find the result may have some un order record, any idea for how to solve it (stream data is not allow to sort)

```
+------------------------------------------+-----+---------+---------+
|window                                    |stock|min_price|max_price|
+------------------------------------------+-----+---------+---------+
|{2023-03-06 17:28:50, 2023-03-06 17:29:00}|e    |475      |475      |
|{2023-03-06 17:28:50, 2023-03-06 17:29:00}|i    |917      |917      |
|{2023-03-06 17:28:50, 2023-03-06 17:29:00}|m    |538      |538      |
|{2023-03-06 17:28:50, 2023-03-06 17:29:00}|r    |270      |270      |
|{2023-03-06 17:28:50, 2023-03-06 17:29:00}|f    |253      |253      |
|{2023-03-06 17:28:50, 2023-03-06 17:29:00}|j    |280      |280      |
|{2023-03-06 17:28:40, 2023-03-06 17:28:50}|i    |503      |775      |
|{2023-03-06 17:28:50, 2023-03-06 17:29:00}|c    |834      |834      |
+------------------------------------------+-----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: window sorted by what field? you can always use the .orderBy(col("key")) function

Comment: because it is steam data from KAFKA, orderBy is not allowed, and it will throw error